# How to create an admob adView dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, android-relativelayout, adview

I have an `admob` `adView` set up and I need to create it dynamically due to a bug in the latest release of course.

I want the ad on the bottom of the screen, and I have a `LinearLayout` which is set to the bottom BUT there are is a restrictions which have to be otherwise the ad won't load. I need to `LinearLayout` to be a certain height (NOT wrap content)

This all works fine with a test ad, but the problem is... I was going to put this layout in a RelativeLayout so that I can align it to the bottom, but as soon as I do- I don't see any ad...

Here is my code `onCreate`:

```
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxx");

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adView);

    layout.addView(adView);


    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    adRequest.addTestDevice("5554");    
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

As I said, the above code works perfectly fine, but I would like to align this on the bottom and inside a relativeLayout, but it has to be done dynamically...

Comment: Can please post your layout file code?

Comment: you should post your layou.xml or refer this link http://jmsliu.com/209/add-google-admob-in-android-application.html

Comment: I'm doing my ads grammatically, due to a bug in the latest adMob SDK which doesn't allow you to create them in the xml itself.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the display height at runtime and set the margin top as per required. Method to calculate height

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();       
        int width = display.getWidth();
```

Comment: That's a good idea, I will def try that tonight-
Any reason you chose display.getWidth() though instead of height?

Answer (score 0):

Your linear layout should be as follow. so your adview will automatically set in bottom of the page.

```
  <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
         android:id="@+id/rootViewGroup"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

hope this will help you .

Comment: ^ Can't add via XML code due to bug in latest version. Dynamic only.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the common layout approach for putting Banner ad under listview or recycler view.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="net.yrom.screenrecorder.fragment.ItemFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_item_list">Here Can Be anything Mostly it's list view</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

`layout.layout_alignParentBottom(true);`